# recorder is not defined at HTMLButtonElement (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC) script for video recording.

Here is code of my View.

```
 <p style="text-align: center;">
        <video id="preview" controls style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238); height: 280px; width: 300px;" muted="muted" ;></video>
    </p>
<div id="container" style="padding:1em 2em; width: 350px; text-align: center;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

I try to replace div with div like this

```
$('#container').replaceWith($('#preview').html('<video controls autoplay src="' + recorder.toURL() + '"></video>'));
```

But I got this error.

> ```
> recorder is not defined at HTMLButtonElement
> ```

How I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my script

```
<script>
var myLink = document.getElementById('next');
myLink.onclick = function functionName() {
    var element = $(".activeQue");
    $(element).removeClass("activeQue").addClass("hiddenQue");
    $(element).next().removeClass("hiddenQue").addClass("activeQue");
    $('#container').replaceWith($('#preview').html('<video controls autoplay src="' + recorder.toURL() + '"></video>'));
}
```

Comment: Where is the recorder variable declared?

Comment: As I understood, there `<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"> </script>` @Webbanditten